# Running mysql command from bat file with redirection

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I have the following batch file:

```
@ECHO on
cd "C:\Program Files\MariaDB\mariadb\bin"
mysql -u root < "C:\database_setup.sql"
```

When I run the command directly in the command line, it works fine. When I run this batch file I get that it's trying to execute:

```
mysql -u root 0<"C:\database_setup.sql"
```

To solve this, I tried to escape the less than sign with:

```
mysql -u root ^< "C:\database_setup.sql"
```

It appears to be correct in the console but it's dumping the mysql options instead of inserting the contents of database_setup.sql.

I'm thinking that this is because the "<" is actually be referred to as a string since I'm escaping it and not as the redirection operator.

How does one accomplish running this command in a batch file (which works fine directly in the console)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following workaround could help you:

```
mysql -u root -e "SOURCE C:\database_setup.sql"
```

Also the following should work:

```
type C:\database_setup.sql | mysql -u root
```